# Почему не работает тип указателя на функцию?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func() {
    cout << "call func" << endl;
}

struct S {
    void(*)() operator () () {
        return func;
    }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s()();
}
```

Получаю ошибку: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Почему не работает void(*)() в качестве типа возврата?
Любым другим способом тип добавить можно, например, через auto, или через function<void()> или через typedef void(*ptf)(); 
Но почему нельзя явно указать сам тип??

Comment: Любым другим способом тип добавить можно, например, через auto, или через function<void()> или через typedef void(*ptf)(); Но почему нельзя явно указать сам тип??

Comment: Вероятно, считает `void(*)()` не типом, а объявлением члена, и требует наличие идентификатора...

Comment: Без идентификатора никак?

Comment: Без - никак. А с ним - как в ответе ниже :)

Comment: `void (* operator()())() { return func; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синтаксис возврата функции в C/C++ очень мудрёный. Допустим вы хотите вернуть другую функцию

```
double func2 ( int x ) {
  return x + 1 ;
}
```

тогда синтаксис будет такой :

```
double ( & operator ( ) ( ) ) ( int ) {
    return func2 ;
}
```

тип возвращающий возвращаемой функции `double`
тип аргументов возвращаемой функции `int`
обрамление скобками со амперсантом `( & operator ( ) ( ) )` означает, что оператор возвращает ссылку на функцию типа `double ( & ) ( int )`

*Можете возвращать не ссылку, а указатель. Никакой разницы.*

Проще сначала задать тип, чтобы не путаться :

```
typedef double TF ( int ) ;
TF & operator ( ) ( ) { 
  return func2 ;
}
```

*в стандарте C++11 можно так :*

```
auto operator ( ) ( ) -> double ( & ) ( int ) {
    return func2 ;
}
```

в вашем примере :

```
void ( & operator ( ) ( ) ) ( ) {
    return func ;
}
```

или

```
typedef void TF ( void ) ;
TF & operator ( ) ( ) {
    return func ;
}
```

или *стандарт C++11*

```
auto operator ( ) ( ) -> void ( & ) ( ) {
    return func ;
}
```

Comment: AlexGlebe, почему вы переделали указатель на ссылку в своем ответе? Применение указателей не комильфо?)

Comment: имя функции/переменной всегда понимается как ссылка на сам объект. А ссылка на функцию имеет у себя бонус автоматической смены на указатель. Я не люблю автоматических смен типов, и люблю, чтобы было всё реально.

Comment: .. см [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zYnaMxTqW)

Comment: AlexGlebe, спасибо, это полезная информация

Comment: AlexGlebe, но я не понимаю, почему это утверждение:
`static_assert(is_same<void(*)(), decltype(func)>::value);`
дает ошибку? Почему func тут не распадается до указателя на себя?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, funс будет тем же самым что и &funс, но &funс сразу возвращает указатель на функцию, а funс (нативно) возвращает тип функции, но автоматически преобразуется к указателю на функцию и становится тем же, что и &funс, верно? А в decltype этого преобразования (function-to-pointer conversions) не происходит, правильно?

Comment: ваш вопрос уже выходит за пределы комментариев. Автоматическое преобразование типов и `is_same` никак с собой не вяжутся. И автоматическое преобразование `int array[12]` -> `int *` не означает, что это **один и тот-же** тип.

Answer (score 3):

На более простом примере.

- Неправильно: `int[10] a = ...;`
- Правильно: `int a[10] = ...;`
- Неправильно: `void (*)() a = ...;`
- Правильно: `void (*a)() = ...;`

Ну и аналогично:

- Неправильно: `void(*)() operator()() {...}`
- Правильно: `void(*operator()())() {...}`

Answer (score -1):

**Вот еще несколько примеров:**

```
// Синтаксис возврата для функции func1():
void func1() { ... }                                        // функция типа void(*)()

void ( *operator()() ) () { return func1; }                 // используя перегрузку оператора () вызова функции

auto operator()() { return func1; }                         // используя auto

auto operator()() -> void(*)() { return func1; }            // используя auto c явным указанием типа функции

std::function<void()> operator()() { return func1; }        // используя std::function

typedef void(*PTF)();                                       // using PTF = void(*)();       
PTF operator ()() { return func1; }                         // используя typedef function pointer

typedef void TF (void);                                     // using TF = void (void);      
TF * operator ()() { return func1; }                        // используя typedef function

// Синтаксис возврата для функции func2():
double func2(int x) { ... }                                 // функция типа double(*)(int)

double ( *operator()() ) (int) { return func2; }            // используя перегрузку оператора () вызова функции

auto operator()() { return func2; }                         // используя auto

auto operator()() -> double(*)(int) { return func2; }       // используя auto c явным указанием типа функции

std::function<double(int)> operator()() { return func2; }   // используя std::function

typedef double(*PTF)(int);                                  // using PTF = double(*)(int);  
PTF operator ()() { return func2; }                         // используя typedef function pointer

typedef double TF (int);                                    // using TF = double (int); 
TF * operator ()() { return func2; }                        // используя typedef function
```